# Will a custom dimension's value be applied to the pageview of the page in which the ga('set') script appears

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to implement a Google Analytics user-level custom dimension on a site.

I have read [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets) that the code to do this looks something like this:

```
ga('set', 'dimension2', value );
```

If I include that script in page X, will the hit for page X's page-view include that dimension/value? Or will it only apply to future hits that that user initiates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're setting a [user level scoped](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en#example-user) CD, it will apply to all previous hits in the session as well.

I'd recommend you do the ga('set') before you perform ga('send'), this way you utilize the pageview hit to set this CD, not the next hit.

Edit:
Your regular implementation looks like this:

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');

ga('set', ...); //do you sets here

ga('send', 'pageview'); //this is the send
</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

Alternatively, you can just run this and just do "set" and "send" separately, though you'd want to execute the set/send very close to when you load the page:

```
 <!-- Google Analytics -->
    <script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

   **//removed ga(send) stuff**

    </script>
    <!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

To verify, use dev tools, look at your networks tab. Search/filter for "collect" you'll see the calls made to GA. Look for the parameters for the call, specificall cd1, cd2, cd3 etc...look for the cd# that's the same index as the cd you've set. Verify the data there is correct.
[image]

Comment: Forgive me I am a little new to GA... I am not manually performing a ga('send'...). I thought that this was performed automatically by the analitics.js when a new page was loaded? If I manually call ga('send') on a pageview won't it double-count the page view?

Comment: the ga('send') is part of the implementation code, you can just take it out. You can also choose to send a non-interaction event as well if that makes it easier for you to implement.

Comment: Last question: is there anyway that you know of to test if this is working? Data doesn't seem to propagate to the GA dashboard for many hours. Can I test to see if it the dimension data is coming in correctly somehow, without having to wait til tomorrow?

Comment: updated answer with screenshot showing chrome dev tools